# Google maps POLYLINE to my GEOLOCATION not working

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-polyline

Im trying to get a polyline to track my geolocation so wherever i walk it will create a polyline showing my track/route on a map
Im using the demo code of CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap, the code for it can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial

This is a what i have tried to get a polyline to follow my tracks

```
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()))
                        .width(5)
                        .color(Color.RED));
```

And here is where i placed my code, but it doesnt successfully work and it keeps crashing when i load the app on my phone

```
private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()))
                        .width(5)
                        .color(Color.RED));
            } else {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                mLastKnownLocation = null;
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Thank you for your time and support

Comment: Can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?